# Why is this border not moving to the vertical center of the parent StackPanel but does so in a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Within my `Grid` I have the following `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4"  Margin="5, 5, 10, 5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow" Orientation="Vertical">
   <Border Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="0 10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
               <Image Source="\Resources\Arrow2 Up.ico"/>
            </Button.Content>
         </Button>
         <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="0 10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Content>
               <Image Source="\Resources\Arrow2 Down.ico"/>
            </Button.Content>
         </Button>
      </StackPanel>
   </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

I have made the background yellow, so we can see the size of the `StackPanel`. The whole thing looks as follows:

[image]

I want to have the button in the vertical center. I can achieve that by replacing the outer `StackPanel` with another `Grid` and we get the following.

[image]

It seems like `StackPanel`s do not know their own actual height but `Grid`s do? Why is that the case, or is there another reason for this behavior?

Comment: A vertical StackPanel arranges its child elements from top to bottom. It's unclear why you expect something else.

Comment: I'm baffled to see a _Needs detail or clarity_ close vote on a question like this that to me is very clear and has exactly the right amount of detail.

Comment: @Clemens Yeah now it is clear. The initial confusion came from the `VerticalAlignment` property of the children, which obviously wouldn't work within a StackPanel. So I kind of approached the whole issue completely from the wrong direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`StackPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=net-5.0) by definition stacks elements vertically from top to bottom or horizontally from left to right (or right to left with `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`) depending on its `Orientation`.

> Arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically.

That is all it does, it does not take into account proportional sizes based on the available space. A [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=net-5.0) on the other hand has columns and rows that can take advantage of [star sizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=net-5.0) to achieve exactly that.

> Columns and rows that are defined within a Grid can take advantage of Star sizing to distribute remaining space **proportionally**. When Star is selected as the height or width of a row or column, that column or row receives a weighted proportion of the **remaining available space**.

In your case you may not even need a `StackPanel`. You could just place your `Border` directly inside the `Grid` and set its `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAligment` properties accordingly e.g:

```
<Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4"  Margin="5, 5, 10, 5" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```